# Net::SCP file uploads are empty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ssh, scp

I am trying to write a string to a file and then upload it to a remote server.

```
Net::SSH.start( "localhost", "root" ) do |ssh|
  Tempfile.open('vh_', Rails.root.join('tmp') ) do |f|
    f.write("FILE_CONTENTS")
    # at this point, i have confirmed that f.path is valid and that file is not empty
    ssh.scp.upload!(f.path, "/remote/path")
    f.close!
  end

  #more ssh commands follow

end
```

The reason for the ssh root@localhost is because this file will (in the future) be uploaded to other servers, using localhost is simply for testing. This code successfully creates the tempfile (with the correct content), but after uploading, the remote file is empty (0 B).

It works fine on my local (dev) machine, but when uploading to the server, the file is empty. My local is running Xubuntu 13.04 and the server is Ubuntu Server 13.10.

Comment: Try to close the file before uploading. It may not be written to the disk when you upload it.

Comment: I have tried closing before uploading. However, the close! method deletes the file.

I have also tried the order of:
f.write
f.close
upload!
f.unlink

Comment: `close!` closes and unlinks (deletes) the file. Try `f.close`, then the uplodad, then `f.unlink`.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I have found the solution (workaround?) to be f.rewind before uploading. No clue why that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

According to the original poster:

> I have found the solution (workaround?) to be f.rewind before uploading. No clue why that makes a difference.